# Painting on one JPanel when two are in the frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, paintcomponent

I have two JPanels inside my program's main JFrame for my GUI. One is a menu and the other should give display some graphics and then later animation. I'm trying to draw inside the latter panel.

Im using intelliJ's grid layout manager so that's made it a bit harder for me to find where to put what code.

Im new to Java so any help on how to paint on the AnimationPanel would be very greatly appreciated.

Here's my attempt so far -

Main Class:

```
public class ProjectileSim {

public static void main(String[] args){
    GUIForm1 gui = new GUIForm1();
    AnimationPanel animationPanel = new AnimationPanel();


}
```

}

AnimationPanel Class:

```
public class AnimationPanel extends JPanel {
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    //axis
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(50, 0, 5, getHeight());
    g.fillRect(0, getHeight() - 50, getWidth(), 5);


    int axisY = 0;
    int axisX = 0;
    int axisYCounter = 1;
    int axisXCounter = 1;

    //axis markers
    while (axisYCounter <= getHeight() / 10) {
        g.fillRect(35, axisY, 20, 5);
        axisY = axisY + 50;
        axisYCounter++;
    }

    while (axisXCounter <= getWidth() / 10) {
        g.fillRect(axisX, getHeight() - 50, 5, 20);
        axisX = axisX + 50;
        axisXCounter++;
    }
}
}
```

GUIForm1 Class: (omitted a lot of this since it is mainly menu related)

```
public class GUIForm1 {


private JPanel MainPanel;
private JPanel MenuPanel;
private JPanel AnimationPanel;



public GUIForm1() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Projectile Motion");
    frame.setContentPane(MainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I see you are painting some rectangles on AnimationPanel, are they visible?

Comment: No, thats my problem. When i make a separate program with the AnimationPanel code and a bit extra, it runs fine. I think could be how the classes interact with eachother that could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You covered AnimationPanel with MainPanel. I commented this line:

`frame.setContentPane(MainPanel);`

and I was able to see your drawings.

Remember to put AnimationPanel on frame by:

`frame.setContentPane(AnimationPanel);`

or other method (use layouts)

Comment: I tried commenting it out and it didnt work when I did it. All i saw was a blank AnimationPanel. Im using a layout manager and it should appear like so - http://gyazo.com/f5381183e38fdde39661ed4d6de4d277 

The light blue section is the AnimationPanel and when i set MenuPanel as the content frame, all of it shows except the drawings.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt see how to notify you. Just one more bit of help with this would be very much appreciated

Comment: Without more info about layout, how you put them, etc, I won't be able to help you, maybe you can post more code. Try to provide minimal example that doesn't work.

Comment: Here's my form made in IntelliJ: gyazo.com/2eee5b08f30ee87d3f11ff06f25fa57a As you can see, the AnimationPanel is the blank light blue part and the MenuPanel is the dark blue part with the components on. They are both contained within MainPanel ( as the black line separating the panels shows) Heres when I run it with no changes: gyazo.com/729e5b9070a5ae71b2c51fab246b1107 When I comment out frame.setContentPane(MainPanel) I am met with a white screen. When replacing it with frame.setContentPane(AnimationPanel) , I have a light blue screen - a blank AnimationPanel.

Comment: My bad, but all the code posted is all there is except for components being declared and other irrelevant parts. I think im gonna try this from a different angle. Thanks for the help though